# How to extract $0.00 in the below screenshot using XPATH? Selenium & Python - Span/Class

Tags: python, selenium

I'm hoping I can get some help as I have tried many iterations of code thus far.

My goal is to extract what today appears to be $0.00 in the below screenshot:
[image]

The associated elements appear as such:

```
<span class="span-title surfaceclass ng-binding">$0.00</span>
```

XPATH:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span
```

CSS Selector:

```
div.rem-padd > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1)
```

CSS Path:

```
html body.ng-scope div#centerContentDiv div.ng-scope div.container.ng-scope div.row div.col-sm-12.col-md-6 div.panel-group div.panel.panel-default div.panel-body div div.bill-info-table div.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12.rem-padd div.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12 div.row div.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-6.col-lg-8.account-summery-data.account-summery-datawithbtn.padding-rightzero span.span-title.surfaceclass.ng-binding
```

**Here is my current code:**

```
water_due = driver.find_elements((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span'))
for value in water_due:
    print(value.text)
```

This code isn't working and I am getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string
```

I've tried several iterations of my code above using class, xpath, css selector, etc and I have not been successful.

I got it to work on another website and essentially what I want is for a value to hold the $0.00. Next month this will have another value so for example, the code at the end would print say: `$34.58` which is currently displayed as `$0.00` on the website.

Any help is appreciated!

I was successful in passing this same logic in a different website and that code looks like so:

```
electric_Due = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p[1]')
for value in electric_Due:
    print(value.text)
```

Not sure why the current one is not working.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in how you're calling this:

```
water_due = driver.find_elements((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span'))
```

If you use two sets of parens, you're constructing a tuple and passing it as the first argument. Selenium expects the first argument to the the `By.XPATH` part.

So I would change it to this:

```
water_due = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span')
```